# WPF: Не обнаруживается словарь со стилями в подпапке (исключение)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В рамках шабона `MVVM`, организовал свой `WPF`-проект следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка (элемент `View`) перестала обнаруживать стили, когда я переместил словарь с этими стилями в папку `Resources`. Естественно, в `App.config.xaml` я прописал адрес к этому словарю:

```
<Application x:Class="ExampleApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Когда словарь со стилями лежал в корне проекта, то этого указания (просто `Source="Styles.xaml"`) было достаточно, что в разметке он обнаруживался и стили применялись. На данный момент, в режиме "Дизайн" отображение корректное, но при компиляции возникает исключение `System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension`, в котором сказано, что стиль, который встречается в разметке первым, не найден.

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится. Проверьте еще раз. Покажите как используете стиль.

Comment: @Андрей, Вот так например:`Style="{StaticResource BasicGroupBox}"`

Comment: Не воспроизводится, создайте пустой проект и попробуйте ещё раз

Comment: @Андрей, воспроизвёл проблему! Вот [ссылка на проект](https://yadi.sk/d/XNFQlTI73NWfAj) на Яндекс Дискe.

Comment: Ага, проблема значит вообще в другом была, поэтому я не мог ее воспроизвести

Comment: @Андрей, мне было только известно, что не обнаруживается стиль, а вот причина этого - уже другое дело...

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что стиль обнаруживался нормально, не обнаруживалось пространство имен (которое вы вообще, кстати, и не используете, зачем оно там добавлено?)

Comment: @Андрей, со временем уберу всё лишнее; сейчас пока беру из примеров и, естественно, пока что не всё понимаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблемной строкой в вашем случае, выступает:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMStyleProblemTest.Resources"
```

Т.к. на самом деле, данного пространства имен не существует в вашем проекте. Т.е. для решения вашей проблемы достаточно убрать данную строку, или в реальности добавить данное пространство имен в проект.

Но, это еще не все, в `App.xaml.cs` в конструкторе вы прописали:

```
using System.Windows;
using MVVMStyleProblemTest.Views;
using MVVMStyleProblemTest.ViewModels;

namespace MVVMStyleProblemTest {
    public partial class App : Application {
        public App() {
            var modelView = new MainWindowView {
                DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()
            };
            modelView.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Пробуем решить проблему, уберем все из конструктора, перегрузим метод `OnStartup`, перенесем ваш код именно туда:

```
using System.Windows;
using MVVMStyleProblemTest.Views;
using MVVMStyleProblemTest.ViewModels;

namespace MVVMStyleProblemTest
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            var modelView = new MainWindowView
            {
                DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()
            };
            modelView.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаемся запустить...
И вуаля! Все работает!

[image]

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Кстати, в моём реальном проекте было `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMStyleProblemTest"` вместо `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMStyleProblemTest.Resources"`; это я при создании тестового проекта ошибся. А пространство имён `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMStyleProblemTest"` было необходимо для пользовательских элементов. Так что без перегрузки метода никак, видимо...

Comment: Перегрузка метода необходима именно для того, что мы не знаем когда точно создастся экземпляр `App`, вы вызвали окно до того как базовый `Application` сделал все необходимые манипуляции, а окно стало само по себе.